# iframe object not work on Altervista domain

Tags: php, iframe

I am trying to upload my website on a free Altervista domain to try some operation and observe if it all works. 
I have problems with some iframe objects, and I want to understand if it's a problem of Altervista settings or something else. In local all works and i already change the server to server connection settings of Altervista (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbPS.jpg)

This is the iframe code

```
<iframe id="iframeClassifica" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen="" src="https://fipavonline.it/main/classifica/18192"></iframe>
```

and this is the website

http://pallavoloremedello.altervista.org/classifica.php

(also http://pallavoloremedello.altervista.org/risultati.php )

Thanks

Comment: May be blocked. (Cross Domain)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You just told us that you _have_ a problem, but you failed to properly describe what that problem actually _is_. Also, whenever possible, please change your language settings for external services, interfaces etc. to English before taking screenshots, so that everyone here can easily understand what the messages in those screenshots are saying to begin with.

Comment: Most probably the fipavonline.it website blocks load requests from outside their domain range.

Comment: On localhost it works so i don't think is the fipavonline.it that blocks requests